# Как получить информацию о пользователе с помощью aiogram/requests, владея ID пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подумал написать БОТа, который будет оповещать меня о смене статуса конкретного пользователя Telegram (online/offline), но не знаю, каким способом можно получить данные о пользователе, зная его ID?

Comment: Скорее всего никак, как минимум не с BotAPI

Comment: Жалко, а я думал, что как-то можно, хотя сам уже не первый день с aiogram вожусь